# emailing selected range only visible cells from excell in vba

Tags: excel, vba, email

i have th below code to send an email from excell which has the selected range of the active sheet in the body of mail

```
  Sub Ticke_status_mail()

   ' Select the range of cells on the active worksheet.
   ActiveSheet.Range("A12:J74").Select

   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Item.To = "xxxx@yyy.com"
      .Item.subject = "Ticket status on " & ActiveSheet.Range("today").Value
      .Item.Send
   End With
End Sub
```

but is is also sending the hidden rows in the selected rang which should not come in the mail, could some one help in selectimg only visible cells in that range....

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A12:J74").Select`, well of course. You are defining the entire range, doesn't matter whether they are hidden or not. Perhaps this could be of assistance [Skipping Hidden Rows](http://excel.tips.net/T002286_Skipping_Hidden_Rows_in_a_Macro.html)

Comment: You could try `ActiveSheet.Range("A12:J74").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select`

Answer (score 1):

try with `ActiveSheet.Range("A12:J74").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).select`